# Error: "bitwise_and_cpu" not implemented for 'Float'

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am looking to generate Intersection over Union (IoU) score for ResNet50 (pretrained) model. Here is my function to calculate IoU score:

```
def IoU(predict: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor):

i = (predict & target).double().sum()
u = (predict | target).double().sum()
x = (i/u)
IoU = x.item()

return IoU
```

And below is a function to implement IoU score:

```
def applyIoU(model, dataset):

IoU_score = []

for i in range(len(dataset)):
    
    image,true_mask = dataset[i]
    x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(image).to('cpu').unsqueeze(0)
    pred_mask = model.predict(x_tensor)
    true_mask = torch.from_numpy(true_mask).to('cpu').unsqueeze(0)
    IoU_score = IoU(pred_mask, true_mask)
    
assert type(true_mask) == torch.Tensor

return IoU_score
```

When I run my codes I get the following error. Is there any other way to get IoU score without using **&** and **|** operators in Pytorch? Thanks

```
    156 
--> 157     i = (predict & target).double().sum()
    158     u = (predict | target).double().sum()
    159     x = (i/u)

RuntimeError: "bitwise_and_cpu" not implemented for 'Float
```

Comment: It's a really bad error message, but I think some of numpy's internal implementation details are leaking out.  And yes, as @user2864740 said, & and | on floats don't really make sense.